# Making CSS column-reverse accessible

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, accessibility

I'm working on a componentized project, which has a component for an Input with a Label. like such:

```
<div>
    <input type={type} value={value} name={name}/> 
    <label>{inputLabel}</label>
</div>
```

The problem is, in a specific case, I'm having to use `flex-direction: column-reverse;` which breaks accessibility in the screen reader. Is there a way I can still reverse the order and not lose the accessibility, without needing to create a new component?

Comment: You can use the "for" keyword in the label tag if something is breaking in terms of accessibility.

Comment: how do you mean, "breaks accessibility"? Your `label` is certainly not programmatically associated with the input, and that is going to cause the screenreader to not announce the input correctly (and this is a WCAG failure and one which automated testing tools like Axe devtools should pick up for you) - but that is true no matter what CSS you apply here.

Comment: My company pointed out that "for" is not enough for some screenreaders and but I added it which solved some issues.

Comment: By "Breaking accessibility" I meant it does not read in the correct order. But this Axe devtools Looks good I'm definitely trying it out. I'm unfamiliar with the programmatic association but will study a bit about it. Thank you.

Comment: “"for" is not enough for some screenreaders” That sounds like BS or a misunderstanding. Plus, right now you are not doing anything to provide an accessible label. https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/input-text-label-for/

Comment: So which issues didn’t the `for` solve, @BrianBenko? Could you me more specific in your question please?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you read this section of the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#accessibility_concerns)

> Accessibility concerns
>
> Using the flex-direction property with values of row-reverse or column-reverse will create a disconnect between the visual presentation of content and DOM order. This will adversely affect users experiencing low vision navigating with the aid of assistive technology such as a screen reader. If the visual (CSS) order is important, then screen reader users will not have access to the correct reading order.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168712/what-is-stack-overflows-take-on-link-only-answers) are not good answers. Add some of the content that addresses the question from the link to the question itself.

Comment: I have Checked this link already, I ended up using javascript to fix the order, but it is not really the clean solution I was hoping for. But thank you both for the links, really liked the info.